# Howto prevent jenkins updating build status in bitbucket

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket

I have got a jenkins pipline which is triggered by any new commit to my development repository at bitbucket.
The pipeline starts multiple instances of a downstream pipeline (slave) with different parameters which is checking out my repo und building the source. The pipeline script for the BUILD pipeline is also from the SCM.

After building each configuration, the result ist reported back to the bitbucket repo by the bitbucket server notifier plugin.
So I got the following reports at bitbucket for each commit:

```
master pipline               build pipline (from SCM)                bitbucket status
===============              =========================               ===================
commit ->   
start build 1      ------>   building (config A)          ------>    1. "build pipline running"
                                                                     2. "build pipline done"
                    <<-------------------------------------------------------------------
posting "build done conf A" to bitbucket ---------------------->>    "build done conf A"

start build 2      ------>   building (config B)          ------>    1. "build pipline running"
                                                                     2. "build pipline done"
                    <<-------------------------------------------------------------------
posting "build done conf B" to bitbucket ---------------------->>    "build done conf B"
```

So at the end I got 3 results at bitbucket:

- "build pipeline done"
- "build done conf A"
- "build done conf B"

But I dont want to have the status of the "build (slave) pipeline" at bitbucket!

So how can I prevent jenkins from propagating the build status of "build pipeline" to the bitbucket server?
I suppose the status is propagated because of the "Pipline script from SCM" option.

Greetings!

Comment: No one has got a solution? :-(